# Can't install Ubuntu 20.04 on Alienware R11 PC

Tags: nvidia, 20.04

I just downloaded the latest LTS ISO (Ubuntu 20.04) and created a bootable USB with Rufus under Windows.

GRUB loads and gives the usual boot options. If I select "Ubuntu" the graphic gets scrumbled and no further progress can be made. See photo:

[image]

If I select "Ubuntu (safe graphic)" the installation process begins, but  because of the limited screen resolution I cannot click 'continue' on a particular screen. See photo:

[image]

I tried moving the window by holding down Alt and dragging the mouse with no success.

This is probably related to graphic issues the Ubuntu installer is having with an NVIDIA RTX 2080 SUPER.

Any way I can install Ubuntu on this machine?

Comment: With Nvidia, secure boot should be off.  Edit the grub kernel boot line (vmlinuz) to include the word nomodeset until proprietary graphics installed.  Try 20.10 for a later kernel.

Comment: Yes, I tried 20.10 and the graphics issues were solved. I probably just go with that one. Currently trying to get 20.10 installed with the Intel RST with the Z490 chipset. That's also not straight-forward (but off-topic on this thread)

Comment: I think that Gnome (the desktop environment used on Ubuntu) uses the Super (Windows) key for dragging windows, not Alt.

Answer (score 4):

The first issue happened because the "Intel Platform Trust" stuff got in the way of you installing an operating system. The simplest way forward would be to:

1. Reboot the machine
2. Enter the BIOS
3. Find something in the security section that says "TPM" or "Intel Platform Trust Technology"
4. Change the setting to disabled
5. Save and Restart

From this point, you should be able to install Ubuntu normally without the "Safe Graphics" mode.