# Ubuntu Certified PC with RTX 3080 (Alienware Ubuntu support)

Tags: nvidia, alienware

I am looking for a Desktop PC with a RTX 3080 for Deep Learning application.
I noticed the Alienware R11 is probably one of the cheapest solutions (I can't build one by myself for external reasons), however, Dell does not officially support Ubuntu and I read about many people having difficulties installing Ubuntu. I mean, in my limited experience, Ubuntu should work on almost everything.

My questions are:

- Do you know if Ubuntu would work on the Alienware R11?
- Do you know any PC with RTX 3080 that offers official support for Ubuntu?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question and answer is probably going to be considered an opinion however, for the time that it's open, you may want to consider something from HP. Last autumn HP announced proper support for Ubuntu on their Z-series of workstations and you can order them with Ubuntu pre-installed.

If you need the RTX3080 specifically, then the HP Z4 G4 Workstation is likely the machine that will give you what you need. Using [the pricing calculator from ZWorkstations](https://zworkstations.com/products/hp-z4-workstation/), you can build one with Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS pre-installed for $3,450 USD (as of the time of this answer).

Speaking from experience, the HP workstations are rock solid and worth the price premium. Dell's Precision line is also pretty decent and can be ordered with Ubuntu pre-installed depending on what country you call home. Lenovo's anvil-like ThinkStations are also great, though a bit more expensive than comparable offerings from HP and Dell.

As for the Alienware R11, you can certainly put Ubuntu 20.04 on the machine, but remember to [disable "Intel Platform Trust"](https://askubuntu.com/a/1304863/1091774) before trying to install.